# Convert UIimage (photo library or camera) into PDF in iPhone Files

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdfkit

1. I include `VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate` in my class
2. To "scan the document", I used this code:

```
    @IBAction func scanButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let scannerViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
        scannerViewController.delegate = self
        present(scannerViewController, animated: true)

    }
```

3. In `viewDidLoad`, I include the `PDFView`

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pdfView = PDFView()

        pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(pdfView)

        pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: startOutlet.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: PDFOutlet.topAnchor).isActive = true

        PDFOutlet.isHidden = true }
```

4. I add the `documentCameraViewController` functions

```
    func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
        guard scan.pageCount >= 1 else {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()

            for i in 0 ..< scan.pageCount {
                if let image = scan.imageOfPage(at: i).resize(toWidth: 250) {
                    print("image size is \(image.size.width), \(image.size.height)")
                    // Create a PDF page instance from your image
                    let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: image)
                    // Insert the PDF page into your document
                    pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage!, at: i)
                }
            }

            // Retrieve raw data of your PDF document
            let data = pdfDocument.dataRepresentation()

            let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let docURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Scanned-Docs.pdf")

            do {
            try data?.write(to: docURL)
            }
            catch(let error)
            {
                print("error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        PDFOutlet.isHidden = false

    }

    func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func documentCameraViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    }

    extension SnapToPDF: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
      // Not used, but necessary for compilation
    }

    extension UIImage {
        func resize(toWidth width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
            let canvas = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(ceil(width/size.width * size.height)))
            return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: canvas, format: imageRendererFormat).image {
                _ in draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvas))
            }
        }
```

5. I want to have a button for users to click the save the PDF that they have selected, but this part of the code isn't working. Everything else above works, and in the app, I can take a photo and resize it, or choose from photo library. Ideally, wanted to show options for the user to save the PDF into their Files in the iPhone, but it is not working. The button does nothing. Please help!

```
    @IBAction func viewPDFButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

            let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let docURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Scanned-Docs.pdf")

            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: docURL.path){
                   pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: docURL)
            }
            else {
                   print("file does not exist..")
            }
        }
```

Comment: THANKS for neatening the code, Tyler! I have found the solution!!! 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller